# R timeSeries Aggregate() Function Not Including First Minute Of Hour

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate

I'm attempting to use the timeSeries package in R to aggregate data from a timeSeries object. I wrote some basic sample code for reference:

```
library(timeSeries)
library(timeDate)
BD <- as.timeDate(paste("2015-01-01", "00:00:00")) # Creates a timeDate.
ED <- as.timeDate(paste("2015-01-31", "23:59:00")) # Creates a timeDate.
DR <- seq(BD, ED, by = 60) # Creates a sequence by minutes in between the 2 dates.

data <- runif(length(DR), 0, 100) # Creating random sample data.

x <- timeSeries(data, DR) # Initializing a timeSeries object from data and DR.
colnames(x) <- "Data" # Renaming column.

by = timeSequence(BD, ED, by = "hour") # Setting the sequence to be aggregated on.
x.agg <- timeSeries::aggregate(x, by, sum) # Aggregating on that sequence.
```

After running the code my head looks like this:

```
> head(x.agg)
GMT
                          Data
2015-01-01 00:00:00   29.71688
2015-01-01 01:00:00 3129.84860
2015-01-01 02:00:00 2398.92438
2015-01-01 03:00:00 3134.78608
2015-01-01 04:00:00 2743.79543
2015-01-01 05:00:00 3159.38404
```

Notice that the first data, "2015-01-01 00:00:00" is significantly less than the other hourly sums, in fact it is exactly the same as the data point in the original data sample:

```
> head(x)
GMT
                        Data
2015-01-01 00:00:00 29.71688
2015-01-01 00:01:00 38.73175
2015-01-01 00:02:00  1.01945
2015-01-01 00:03:00 89.64938
2015-01-01 00:04:00 34.23608
2015-01-01 00:05:00 90.48571
```

Doing some investigating into where the sum is coming from, the aggregation for the "2015-01-01 01:00:00" hour is a summation of all the time in between (inclusive) "2015-01-01 00:01:00" and "2015-01-01 01:00:00" as shown code-wise here:

```
> sum(x[2:61,])
[1] 3129.849

> x.agg[2,]
GMT
                        Data
2015-01-01 01:00:00 3129.849
```

What I need is for the aggregation to sum across all the data points within the "00:00:00" hour, that is to say, the aggregation for "2015-01-01 00:00:00" should be equivalent with:

```
> sum(x[1:60,])
[1] 3065.829
```

including the first minute of that hour and *not* the first minute of the next hour like aggregation is doing. It seems to be that the aggregation function is considering the first minute of the hour to *not* be part of that hour, which I find very strange. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The results you obtained is expected. You need to pay attention to the doc concerning `?aggregate`.  Something like `aggregate.ts(x,nfrequency = 1/60)` yield better results but it sill misses your objective.

Comment: I definitely see that the way aggregate is working is simply inherent to the function. I'm hoping to find a work around as I would like to be able to use the timeSeries package and having my data aggregated in not the way I need it throws a wrench in that endeavor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found an answer to my own question and it involves modifying the source code for the `timeSeries::aggregate()` function. To achieve what I wanted in my above question, go to the source code of the timeSeries package, which is most easily found by downloading the tar.gz file off CRAN here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeSeries/index.html

Extract the file and make your way into the R folder inside the timeSeries folder. Find the "stats-aggregate.R" file and open it in R. In it, you'll see `.aggregate.timeSeries` function. Inside that function, what needs to be changed to get the result I wanted is that the `+1`'s need to be removed from line 80 and 81. After doing so, the aggregate function will aggregate in the way I wanted it to.

Here is the modified function in text (I changed its name as well):

```
`modTSAgg <- 
 function(x, by, FUN, ...)
{
# A function implemented by Yohan Chalabi and Diethelm Wuertz

# Description:
#   Aggregates a 'timeSeries' object

# Details:
#   This function can be used to aggregate and coursen a
#   'timeSeries' object.

# Arguments:
#   x - a 'timeSeries' object to be aggregated
#   by - a calendarical block
#   FUN - function to be applied, by default 'colMeans'
#   ... - additional argument to be passed to the newly generated
#       'timeSeries' object

# Value:
#   Returns a S4 object of class 'timeSeries'.

# Examples:
# Quarterly Aggregation:
#   m = matrix(rep(1:12,2), ncol = 2)
#   ts = timeSeries(m, timeCalendar())
#   Y = getRmetricsOptions("currentYear"); Y
#   from = paste(Y, "04-01", sep = "-"); to = paste(Y+1, "01-01", sep = "-")
#   by = timeSequence(from, to, by = "quarter") - 24*3600; by
#   ts; aggregate(ts, by, sum)
# Weekly Aggregation:
#   dates = timeSequence(from = "2009-01-01", to = "2009-02-01", by = "day")
#   data = 10 * round(matrix(rnorm(2*length(dates)), ncol = 2), 1); data
#   ts = timeSeries(data = data, charvec = dates)
#   by = timeSequence(from = "2009-01-08",  to = "2009-02-01", by = "week")
#   by = by - 24*3600; aggregate(ts, by, sum)

# FUNCTION:

# Check Arguments:
if (!((inherits(by, "timeDate") && x@format != "counts") ||
      (is.numeric(by) && x@format == "counts")))
  stop("'by' should be of the same class as 'time(x)'", call.=FALSE)

# Extract Title and Documentation:
Title <- x@title
Documentation <- x@documentation

# Make sure that x is sorted:
if (is.unsorted(x))
  x <- sort(x)

# Sort and remove double entries in by:
by <- unique(sort(by))

INDEX <- findInterval(x@positions, as.numeric(by, "sec"))
INDEX <- INDEX
is.na(INDEX) <- !(INDEX <= length(by))

# YC : ncol important to avoid problems of dimension dropped by apply
data <- matrix(apply(getDataPart(x), 2, tapply, INDEX, FUN), ncol=ncol(x))
rownames(data) <- as.character(by[unique(na.omit(INDEX))])
colnames(data) <- colnames(x)
ans <- timeSeries(data, ...)

# Preserve Title and Documentation:
ans@title <- Title
ans@documentation <- Documentation

# Return Value:
ans

  }


setMethod("aggregate", "timeSeries", function(x, by, FUN, ...)
  modTSAgg(x, by, FUN, ...))


# until UseMethod dispatches S4 methods in 'base' functions
 aggregate.timeSeries <- function(x, ...) modTSAgg(x, ...)`
```